# 'OnParticleCollision ' does not work in webgl build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system, unity-webgl

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ParticleSystemCollisionManager : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other) {
        // work on pc build, webplayer build
        //when switch to webgl build, it work in editor
        //but after building, run webgl build in browser, it does not work 

        Debug.Log("Collision on " + other.name);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I build a game [TMS](https://github.com/tim-hub/TiminesSweeper-3D-/blob/master/Assets/_Scripts/ParticleSystemCollisionManager.cs)

It worked on pc/[web playter](http://www.kongregate.com/games/tim_w1/tms). And it worked in editor (webgl build setting) too. But after I build it to webgl, it does not work. It seemed that `OnParticleCollision` does not run.

Do you know the reason? Could you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

- Increase the `Collision Quality` in `Collision`, and do not forget set the mode to `world` and `3d`.

[image]

and the reason is [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysCollisionModule.html):

> Collision Quality:
>   This affects how “watertight” the collisions are - at lower quality levels, particles may sometimes pass through colliders (World mode only).